# Problema en JavaScript para invertir elementos de array con bucle for

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Partiendo de una variable dada, tengo que mostrar sus elementos en orden inverso dentro de un elemento h2 existente en el html que llama al script. Me gustaría crear un nuevo array con un bucle for con el orden inverso de los elementos, y mostrarlo en pantalla con sus elementos separados por comas. Con mi código actual sólo consigo que muestre una serie de números. No sé qué es lo que está mál en el código.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Código javascript:

```
var cosas = ["inicio", true, "casa", "coche", "perro", 124, "fin"];
var cosasInverso = [];
for(let i = cosas.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) { 
     cosasInverso += cosas.push(i);
}
var arrayInverso = document.getElementById("enlace");
arrayInverso.innerHTML = cosasInverso;
```

Código HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Título página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id = "enlace"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mirá de nuevo esta línea: `cosasInverso += cosas.push(i);`. ¿Qué estás _pusheando_?

Comment: Y tambén... por ciudado... que devuelve la función `push`?

Comment: Aunado a lo que mencionó padaleiana, estás _pusheando_ i, es decir las posiciones del arreglo (en forma de número), si entendí bien...

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo creo un nuevo array cosasInverso con los 7 elementos del array cosas pero en orden inverso? ¿Se puede hacer mediante un bucle for? ¿Cómo sería el código?

Comment: Debés _pushear_ en `cosasInverso` (no en `cosas`) lo que está en `cosas` en la posición `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui la solución que propuse en el comentario.

```js
    var cosas = ["inicio", true, "casa", "coche", "perro", 124, "fin"];
    var cosasInverso = [];
    //Recorres el array en orden inverso
    for(let i = cosas.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) { 
         cosasInverso.push(cosas[i]); //Agregas el elemento al nuevo array
    }
    var arrayInverso = document.getElementById("enlace");
    arrayInverso.innerHTML = cosasInverso;
```

```html
<div id="enlace" />
```

Saludos

Comment: ¡Los comentarios son efímeros! Escribí _en la respuesta_ lo que habías escrito en el comentario que mencionás, y no olvides describir lo que hace este código, ya que las respuestas _son para toda la comunidad_, no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta) :)

Comment: Eso fue lo que hice, propuse usar un `for` de la manera en que está en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo dos métodos:

1. El del bucle `for`: *(ver mejora de este código en comentarios de @Pipe en esta respuesta)*

```js
var cosas = ["inicio", true, "casa", "coche", "perro", 124, "fin"];
var cosasInverso = [];
inverso = cosas.length;
cosasInverso = []
for (i = 0; i < cosas.length; i++) {
  cosasInverso.push(cosas[inverso-1])
  inverso--
}
var arrayInverso = document.getElementById("enlace");
arrayInverso.innerHTML = cosasInverso;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Título página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id = "enlace"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Con `reverse`:

```js
var cosas = ["inicio", true, "casa", "coche", "perro", 124, "fin"];
var arrayInverso = document.getElementById("enlace");
reverso = cosas.reverse();
arrayInverso.innerHTML = reverso;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Título página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id = "enlace"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explicación:**

Javascript ya dispone de una función para reordenar un array en orden inverso llamada [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Su documentación dice:

> El método reverse() invierte el orden de los elementos de un array in
> place. El primer elemento pasa a ser el último y el último pasa a ser
> el primero.

Comment: Hola :-) . Gracias por tu respuesta. Me vale ya que consigo lo que quiero pero me gustaría saber si hay algún modo sencillo de hacer lo mismo sin usar .reverse.

Comment: @EvilCode De hecho, `.reverse` es la manera _sencilla_. La que tiene más pasos es la del bucle (lo que estás tratando de hacer).

Comment: @EvilCode Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, recarga la página para verla. He agregado la solución con el `for` tambien.

Comment: Para la solucion del ciclo... para que tener una variable inverso y otra i (la cual no usas) porque no hacer `for (i = cosas.length-1; i>=0; i--) { cosasInverso.push(cosas[i]); }` ?

Comment: @Pipe Opiniones y soluciones hay para todos los gustos.  Siempre hay mejores formas de hacer las cosas. Fíjate que mi primera solución, la del reverse, que parecia la más cómoda y rápida segun mi punto de vista, no l a ha querido. Queria un `for` y lo he hecho como me ha salido, sin pensar demasiado tampoco, pues tenia prisa. Tu aporte está bien, si funciona, pero no voy a hacer código a medida cada vez que me pidan cambios, por lo tanto te invito a que postees tu respuesta para que la comunidad lo sepa tambien.

Comment: Y he hecho lo del `for` porque nadie lo habia posteado aún, y también me parecia facil de hacer, sin tanto lio como me parecia lo que el hacia, sino de forma practica y rapida.  Si hubiera habido alguien que ya hubiera posteado una respuesta con un `for` ya no me hubiera preocupado de hacerlo, pero me parecia triste dejarlo con las ganas sabiendo que se podia hacer tambien y que no era tanto esfuerzo. Podias haberlo hecho tu mismo, estabas en la conversación desde el inicio, y no lo has hecho, y parece que despiertes ahora, bueno, pues me parece bien que la pongas por ti mismo. Es tuya, no mia

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestro interés. Es mi primera consulta. Creedme que valoro mucho cada aportación.
@Pipe He probado tu solución y funciona como yo estaba buscando. Es perfecta. Muchas gracias.
Doy por solucionada la consulta. Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: @EvilCode Si esta respuesta cumplimenta correctamente a tu pregunta, debes aceptarla para que tu pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. En este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) tienes instrucciones de cómo se tratan las respuestas y en este otro [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428) el porque es importante aceptar respuestas acertadas y cómo se aceptan. Los agradecimientos muestran muy buena educación, pero aquí se agradece tambien aceptando las respuestas correctas.

Comment: O espera a que @Pipe ponga la suya y la aceptas, pero no te vayas con la solución y sin aceptar ninguna respuesta, porque de tanto en tanto las preguntas sin respuesta aceptada se relanzan a la comunidad.

Comment: @masterguru He probado tu código y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones. Aceptada tu respuesta.

Comment: @Evilcode Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio. De todos modos, si Pipe publica su respuesta siempre puedes cambiar la aceptación de la respuesta sin problema marcándola a ella, y seria lo más recomendable  sabiendo que finalmente usas su aporte y que te convence más.