# Iteracion regresiva de un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, while

queria saber si la unica manera de iterar de forma regresiva un array es usando el metodo reverse()
como en este ejemplo

```
let arr = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70];

let array = arr.reverse()

function iteracionReversaWhile(){
let i = 0
while (i  < array.length) {
  console.log(array[i])
  i++
```

}}

ya que intente haciendolo de esta forma con el ciclo For, sin embargo me sale undefined no se por que

```
for (let numero = arr[arr.length-1]; numero > array.length; numero--) {
   console.log(array[numero])
    
}
 }
```

si pueden darme pistas seria de gran ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema en JavaScript para invertir elementos de array con bucle for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514211/problema-en-javascript-para-invertir-elementos-de-array-con-bucle-for)

Answer (score 0):

Su error está en la condición de for: `numero > array.length` es `false`, necesita `numero > 0`