# Crear una funcion que reciba un array y devuelva un array invertido, ej: [3,7,2] el array de salida es [2,7,3]. No puedo hacerlo con function!

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de hacer la consigna que se ve en el título, estoy recién empezando pero me pierdo mucho. Puedo hacerlo sin function pero el ejercicio pide que sea una función, como hago para mostrarlo en un alert o en consola? Necesito que lo que introduzco se muestre su posición y la nueva posición. Hace dos días estoy dando vueltas.

```
<script>


var arrayNumeros = [5];
var numeros = [arrayNumeros];
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    numeros[i]=parseInt(prompt("Ingresar valores numericos del array: "));
    var invertido = invertir[i];
}

var mostrar = invertir();
function invertir(numeros) {
    var arrayInvertido= [];
    //esta variable va decrementando (-1)        Mientras que esta variable va incrementando (++) así se invierte el array.
    for (var posicion = numeros.length -1, i=0 ; posicion >=0 ; posicion--) {
        arrayInvertido[i]=numeros[posicion];
        
    }
    return arrayInvertido;
}

console.log("Array invertido: "+arrayInvertido);
```

Comment: Tenes grandes errores. A simple vista tu código no funciona por distintos motivos, desde usar variables que no existen hasta llamar a funciones sin pasar los parámetros necesarios. Te vendría bien repasar línea por línea para ver entendes lo que has intentado hacer

Comment: Hola Marcos buenas tardes, estoy confundido principalmente porque copié y pegué de classroom el código que hizo el profesor para explicarlo, solamente había que mostrar en pantalla supuestamente porque en la clase hizo este mismo ejercicio así como está. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema en JavaScript para invertir elementos de array con bucle for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514211/problema-en-javascript-para-invertir-elementos-de-array-con-bucle-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la línea de tu código una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```js
function invertir(numeros) {
  var invertido = [];
  for (var posicion = numeros.length - 1, i = 0; posicion >= 0; posicion--, i++) {
    invertido[i] = numeros[posicion];
  }
  return invertido;
}

var numeros = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  numeros[i] = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar valores numericos del array: "));
}
var mostrar = invertir(numeros);
console.log("Array: ", numeros);
console.log("Array invertido: ", mostrar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Con el método [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) lo tienes fácil:

```js
var numeros = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  numeros[i] = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar valores numericos del array: "));
}
console.log("Array invertido: " + numeros.reverse());
```

Pero si te piden que lo tengas en otra función simplemente hazlo asi (aunque es tonteria, pero bueno):

```js
var numeros = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  numeros[i] = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar valores numericos del array: "));
}

function alreves(numeros) {
  return numeros.reverse()
}

console.log("Array invertido: " + alreves(numeros));
```

O si no te dejan usar el método reverse() y te obligan a jugar con arrays, etc... como has dicho en los comentarios, esto te puede servir (extrapolado de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514211/problema-en-javascript-para-invertir-elementos-de-array-con-bucle-for/514217#514217)):

```js
var numeros = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  numeros[i] = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar valores numericos del array: "));
}

function alreves(numeros) {
  let salida = []
  for (var i = numeros.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    salida.push(numeros[i]);
  }
  return salida;
}
console.log("Array invertido: " + alreves(numeros));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Si le pregunté a mi profesor varias posibilidades pero me dijo que tome el camino que estaba haciendo porque la consigna pide que sea con un function() y yo me estoy volviendo loco :'(

Comment: Actualizad la página y mirad mi actualización de la respuesta... que yo sepa no dice que no sea una función "built-in", simplemente que lo quiere en otra funcion, pues eso he hecho :-)

Comment: Ahí está, muchas gracias! Si la verdad que es mucho más fácil y aún mejor. Como estabamos viendo los temas de length, arrays y funciones pidió que sea con eso. Pero no encuentro otra solución de esa manera así que trato de utilizar algo similar a lo que resolviste. Gracias!

Comment: Acabo de agregar lo que has dicho en tu último comentario en mi respuesta, y verás que me refiero a una pregunta duplicada muy parecida. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que requieres es hacer tu misma funcion de reverso te podira funcionar algo asi:

```js
let numeros = [];
let cantidadNumeros = Number(prompt('Cantidad de numeros a ingresar'));

for(let i = 0; i < cantidadNumeros; i++){
    numeros.push(Number(prompt(`Ingresa el numero [${i + 1}]=`)));
}


let invertirArreglo = (arregloAInvertir) => {
    let arregloInvertido = [];
    for(i = arregloAInvertir.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        arregloInvertido.push(arregloAInvertir[i]);
    }
    return arregloInvertido;
}

let arregloInvertido = invertirArreglo(numeros);
console.log(arregloInvertido);
```

O si lo que requieres algo ya con las mismas funciones del arreglo seria algo asi...

```js
let numeros = [];
let cantidadNumeros = Number(prompt('Cantidad de numeros a ingresar'));

for(let i = 0; i < cantidadNumeros; i++){
    numeros.push(Number(prompt(`Ingresa el numero [${i + 1}]=`)));
}


let invertirArreglo = arregloAInvertir => arregloAInvertir.reverse();

let arregloInvertido = invertirArreglo(numeros);
console.log(arregloInvertido);
```